# store arraylist value to different textview

Tags: android, arraylist

Hello I set values in `ArrayList` Now how can I store that values in different textviews.

For Example:

```
ArrayList<String> mylist =new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++)
{
    //Here mylist contains 10 values and I have 10 different textviews. Now How can i add values 1 to 10 in different textview. set value to First textview 1,second textview to 2 etc.
}
```

Please Help me to find this.

Comment: How can we store values in different textview in for loop. textview1.settext(first value of arraylist); textview2.settext(secondvalue from arraylist); and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the way::

```
TextView []tv=new TextView[10];
tv[0]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.____);
tv[1]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.____);
tv[2]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.____);
tv[3]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.____);
tv[4]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.____);
tv[5]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.____);
tv[6]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.____);
tv[7]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.____);
tv[8]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.____);
tv[9]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.____);

for(int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++)
{
  tv[i].setText(mylist.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Oh...great that you change the Correctness of the Answer..: Cheers..!!

Answer (score 4):

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);

            ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
            mylist.add("1");
            mylist.add("2");
            mylist.add("3");
            mylist.add("4");
            LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            for (int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) 
            {
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                tv.setText(mylist.get(i));
                layout.addView(tv);
            }
```

And XML File

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why this answer got downVote, It is an valid answer!!

Answer (score 2):

If u have the same no of text views and the data then create a array of views then use for loop as:

```
      ArrayList<String> mylist =new ArrayList<String>();
        mylist.add("1st");
        mylist.add("2nd");
        mylist.add("3rd");
        mylist.add("4th");
//        mylist.add("5th");
        one=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        two=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        three=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        four=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        ArrayList<TextView>text=new ArrayList<TextView>(Arrays.asList(one,two,three,four));


        for(int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++)
        {
            text.get(i).setText(mylist.get(i));
            //Here mylist contains 10 values and I have 10 different textviews. Now How can i add values 1 to 10 in different textview. set value to First textview 1,second textview to 2 etc.
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need loop here

you need to call `textView.setText(mylist.get(0));` ... u need to call this for 10 times with increasing value in get method.. and with diff text view instances.

**Edit :as par your comment:** here suppose you have created

```
TextView [] tv; // you need to initialized array here with textviews
ArrayList<String> mylist =new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++)
{

tv[i].setText(mylist.get(i));
   }
```

Comment: But size() of arraylist is not fix.

Comment: then how is the size of TextView is fixed? if it is not fixed you can create array of TextViews, and according to size of list, you can call this in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Then you dont need of for loop. just set text to Your text views manually

as

```
ArrayList<String> mylist =new ArrayList<String>();
TextView txt1 = (TextView)findviewbyId(R.id.txt1);
txt1.setText(mylist.get(0);

....//upto 10 textViews

TextView txt10 = (TextView)findviewbyId(R.id.txt10);
txt10.setText(mylist.get(9);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++)
{
    TextView tv = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("textView"+i, "id",getPackageName())); 
    tv.setText(mylist.get(i));
}
```

I'm not sure that is you want to do. I used the [`getIdentifier`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method to retrieve your textViews.
Else, you can inflate your textViews in a loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++)
{
    TextView tv = (TextView)LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.myTextView, null); 
    tv.setText(mylist.get(i));
}
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++)
{
  tv[i].setText(mylist.get(i));
}
```